# Unix dialog: how to change button text

Tags: unix, dialog

Regarding the unix dialog textbook, is it possible to change the `<EXIT>` button text to something else?

Here's the command I use:

```
dialog --backtitle "Back Title" --title "Title" --textbox test.txt 80 80
```

[image: dialog textbox]

Ideally, I would like to have two buttons here:

1. **Accept**
2. **Decline**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not explicitly stated in [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog), you can use an extra button:

```
dialog --backtitle "Back Title" --title "Title" --ok-label "Accept" \
     --extra-button --extra-label "Decline" --textbox test.txt 40 40
```

(The extra button has a default return value of 3.)